# Seam & multiple wars: Contexts.getSessionContext() is null in other war

Tags: java, session, seam, packaging

I am using Seam 2.2.1.CR1 on Weblogic 10.3.2 and JSF 1.2.

I have an ear application with 2 war files. The first war is a JSF / Seam application, the second one does have JSF / Seam, but also has some Servlets pages as well.

When I set things in the Session context in the first web application:

```
Contexts.getSessionContext().set("pimUser", pimUser);
```

I can inject it normally in Seam components in the second war. However, if I try to get the outjected pimUser from a Servlet, I cannot access it:

```
PimUser user1 = (PimUser) Contexts.getSessionContext().get("pimUser");
```

The Contexts.getSessionContext() is null. I noticed that the Javadoc of the

```
org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts
```

Says:

> ```
> Provides access to the current contexts associated with the thread.
> ```
>
> Author(s): Gavin King Thomas Heute

Does this mean that the 2 war files are supposed to have different `Contexts.getSessionScope()`?

I found a way which does allow me to access it through the Session like this:

```
PimUser user2 = (PimUser) httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute("pimUser");
```

The latter way, however does not seem to be a correct one. I would like to access Seam session context through Seam.

I found that there used (?) to be issues with Seam and multi-war applications ([link](http://seamframework.org/Community/MultipleWarsInEarWorking)), however, these are supposed to have been resolved by 2.2.0.GA.

Comment: JEE 5 Tutorial says: You can associate object-valued attributes with a session by name. Such attributes are accessible by any web component **that belongs to the same web context** and is handling a request that is part of the same session. Both war (You can think of war as a web context) do not share their contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular servlet does not get access to the Seam contexts by default: [Replacing servlets with Seam resources](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/ReplacingServletsWithSeamResources). You need to integrate it first by either [wrapping the call in Seam Contexts](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/ReplacingServletsWithSeamResources#H-WrappingTheCallInSeamContexts) or [replacing the servlet with a Seam `AbstractResource`](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/ReplacingServletsWithSeamResources#H-ServingTheContentAsASeamResource).

I used both ways before and they work perfectly. Personally, I prefer the `AbstractResource` because you can get rid of the corresponding `web.xml` configuration.